# IOS 3d for the experts

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, 3d

I've developed a few simple iOS apps, and I'm looking to develop a simple maze game. What I'm looking to do is really basic, so I'm looking for some guidance on which way to go.

Here is basically what I'm trying to do: simple escape-the-maze game where I read in a 2 dimensional array and that makes my maze.

I want the perspective to be standing in the middle of each square, and when you flick or hit a button, it will advance one square, and you can turn left or right. I'd like to be able to apply textures to the ways based on the numbers in the array, and I'd really like to see the movement of the wall moving towards me then stop.

The walls will always be the same height, and the maze will be simple square blocks, although I do want it to be able to hand rooms that might be more than 2x2 , like maybe 4x4, and be able to handle rendering that.

I'm not sure if trying to do something in OpenGL would be overkill since my requirements are really basic. Like I mentioned, it won't be a free move; it will be advance one square each time you hit a button and turn left or right.

I have read something about ray casting for this sort of thing but am not sure how I would accomplish this in iOS. Also I'd like to have the maze not take up the whole screen, maybe 2/3, while the rest is standard iOS controls like buttons and labels, and a background behind it.

What books or articles should I read to help me? I'd prefer not to use a 3rd party engine since this seems really basic.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Core Animation, which is much easier than OpenGL. If you import QuartzCore into your project, you can position any view in 3D as follows:

```
//set the view's 2D position so that the vanishing point is the middle
//of the screen - use the same centre for every view
view.center = CGPointMake(window.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, window.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);

//create a 3d transform
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = -1.0f/500.0f; // this sets the 3D perspective

//you can transform the view in 3D relative to the camera
//this rotates the view by 45 degrees about the Y axis
//but you can also scale, translate, etc using equivalent functions
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, M_PI_4, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)

//transform the view in 3D
view.layer.transform = transform;
```

So if you create your walls as UIImageViews, you can arrange them into a room by transforming each one individually using the logic above.

Comment: I have tried your above code by adding a image in the middle of my screen that is 426 x 426 and changed the view.  to my UIImage view but all it does is makes the image short and wider than it is now. DId I miss something?

Comment: Ok so my mistake was i had my iPad in landscape and the view was in portrait. so if my overall window for my walls is 426 and I want that centered on the screen how would i apply the perspective to that? also id like to have it be 4 walls deep to almost the center where it will be an open square.

Comment: Create a view for your "overall window" and place it Iin the middle of the screen, then put your wall views in the center of that view. Only apply perspective to the walls, not the window view itself.

Comment: Basically without the transform applied, all your wall images should be on top of one another in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Ok I'm string to get what yiur saying. Under for my walls to move into the distance and he smaller as they get farther away do I need to make small images of every wall type or can I use the same one and just scale it somehow. I started looking in the the catransform3dscale but I Didn't seem to scale the image right. I I scaled the x y only to say .75 it didnt scale it image down proportionally like I would have thought it would. Should I be using that or a different scaling function. I'd like to avoid at all possible make 4 sets of every wall tile. Oh an thanks for your help so far

Comment: The walls will scale automatically when you move them further way using CATransform3DTranslate. You don't need to scale them yourself, just move them around in the XYZ axes and the 3D engine takes care of the rest.

Comment: OK so I must be missing something simple. I have a couple images id like to add to show what I'm getting.

Comment: OK so I must be missing something simple. I have a couple images id like to add to show what I'm getting some weird results. I have placed my image onto of another view on the righthand side of the screen.  Check out this link to a page that has pic and the code. Sorry I couldn't figure out how to add the pics and code to this comment. [link](http://web.me.com/tferro1/Site/objc.html)